# Suspicious traffic in nethogs on fresh install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, malware

Earlier today google said that unusual traffic was emanating from my computer and gave me a captcha.  I got curious and installed nethogs.  Everything appears normal except for an unknown program running as root.  It connects to seemingly random ip addresses using very high port numbers (from 40000-60000).  The foreign ip rotates every few minutes.  This is not happening on my other ubuntu computer.

I actually did a fresh install of ubuntu (moving from 14.04 to 16.04) and upon reboot the program is still there occasionally sending and receiving data.  Attached is a screenshot.  Please help me figure out what this traffic is!  Have I been hacked?

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have a dynamic DNS service or something of the sort?

Comment: Try to do a full wireshark capture, or a 'tcpdump -v -s0 -X -i eth0 -w dump.bin -c 100000' . You can then look deeper into the traffic (dumped to file dump.bin). Also try "watch -t 'sudo netstat -navp --inet' " to find out which process is doing this.

Comment: You should be able to list all processes using ports 40000-60000 with: `netstat -tupan | awk -F' +|/' 'NR<=2 || ($7 >= 40000 && $7 <= 60000)'`  or   `netstat -tupan | awk 'NR<=2 || /[45][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\//'` if your `awk` doesn't support regexps as the field separator.

Comment: btw, is your ubuntu box doing NAT or IP Masquerading for other hosts on the network?

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, I am still confused however.  When I watch  "watch -t 'sudo netstat -navp --inet' " I never see the relevant ip addresses appear.  I do see many 0.0.0.0:* entries and the PID/Program name reads as 1948/dnsmasq.  To my knownledge my computer was not doing any odd dns stuff or ip masquerading.  It's just a normal desktop.  But could this be what's causing the weird nethog listings?

Comment: Also, when I run the netstat commands cas provided no active Internet connections are listed, even though NetHogs shows a connection using a port in that range at that very moment.

Comment: the connections may be very short-lived and gone by the time you run `netstat`.  `watch` runs every two seconds by default, so that doesn't help find short-lived connections, either.   BTW, `dnsmasq` is a DNS resolver, it's probably just doing dns queries to remote dns servers like it's supposed to.

Comment: It's been a while since this was asked, but I just ran into this on one of my servers. After going through the TCP dump it's clear this is a syn scan against my server. In my case, it's constant, from multiple hosts, so I assume it's a botnet, or shodan, who knows. But there has been no breach in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the `unknown TCP` message confuse you ,Nethogs didn't have enough data for the connection to identify the process uniquely.

You can check the process through the following commands :

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 54617
netstat -tulpn | grep 37804
```

Do not worry the output will confirm that the tow ports doesn't have any process.

Also you can use [unhide-tcp](http://linux.die.net/man/8/unhide-tcp) to find hiden process through the command `unhide-tcp`.